# Не работает второй фильтр отдельно и совместно с первым, в чем проблема?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

Всем привет! Не судите строго, но я пока новичок. Задача состоит в следующем. В БД хранятся статьи, которые можно отфильтровать по двум параметрам(1 - станции метро: 2 - квартиры). Первый фильтр работает. Выбираем Бульвар Рокоссовского показываются статьи с этой станцией. Загвоздка состоит во втором параметре. Что бы я не делал он фильтрует не корректно. Когда я выбираю значения из второго фильтра, он убирает статьи , которые соответствуют первым 2-м станциям.
База данных

```
SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET AUTOCOMMIT = 0;
START TRANSACTION;
SET time_zone = "+00:00";
CREATE TABLE `city` (
  `id` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `metroid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `metro` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `flatid` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `room` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `texts` text CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `price` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
-- Дамп данных таблицы `city`
INSERT INTO `city` (`id`, `metroid`, `metro`, `flatid`, `room`, `texts`, `price`) VALUES
(1, 1, 'Бульвар Рокоссовского', 1, '1к-квартира', 'Снимем 1-комнатную квартиру на длительный срок. Платежеспособные молодые люди, состоящие в официальном браке. Супруга - дизайнер интерьера в архитектурном бюро на ул. Халтуринская, 6А, супруг - специалист по системному анализу и управлению в крупной IT-компании. Без вредных привычек, детей и животных. Рассматривают квартиру с косметическим ремонтом, с мебелью и бытовой техникой, этаж выше первого. Бюджет до 37 тыс. Регистрация не нужна. Страховой депозит оплачивают в полном объёме.', 37000),
(2, 1, 'Бульвар Рокоссовского', 1, '1к-квартира', 'Молодая семейная пара (29/33 года), без детей, но с маленькой собачкой породы гладкошерстный пинчер. Гарантируют, что питомец приучен ко всему. Согласны прописать в договоре все моменты, связанные с проживанием животного в квартире. Снимут 1-комнатную квартиру попроще. Устроит вариант чистой квартиры, укомплектованной мебелью и техникой. Бюджет до 32 тыс. Регистрация не нужна.', 37000),
(3, 1, 'Бульвар Рокоссовского', 2, '2к-квартира', 'Снимем 2-комнатную квартиру для семейной пары славян с дочкой 13 лет. Граждане РФ, прописка МО, без вредных привычек, платежеспособные. Территориальная привязка к школе N 1797 на ул. Глебовская, 10Б. Необходима квартира с раздельными комнатами, косметическим ремонтом, укомплектованная мебелью и бытовой техникой. Бюджет до 45 тыс. Ищем как можно ближе к школе по адресу ул. Бойцовая, 6, корп. 8а. Регистрация не нужна. Страховой депозит оплачивают в полном объёме.', 45000),
(4, 1, 'Бульвар Рокоссовского', 2, '2-к квартира ', 'Клиенты: семья москвичей с двумя детьми - 9 и 14 лет, без животных. Квартира нужна на полтора-два года - строят свой дом в новой Москве. Рассматривают двушку или трёшку с бюджетом до 50 тыс, можно пустую. Регистрация не нужна. Страховой депозит оплачивают в полном объёме.', 45000),
(5, 2, 'Преображенская Площадь', 1, '1к-квартира', 'Ищем 1-комнатную квартиру для молодой семейной пары. Платежеспособные граждане, чистоплотные, без вредных привычек, детей и домашних питомцев. Клиенты готовы заехать в ближайшее время. Интересует чистая квартира, с необходимой бытовой техникой и мебелью. желательно поближе к ул. Богородский Вал, 6, корп. 1 (супруга работает управляющим салона красоты по этому адресу). Бюджет до 35 тыс. Регистрация не нужна. Страховой депозит оплачивают в полном объёме.', 35000),
-- Структура таблицы `country`
CREATE TABLE `country` (
  `id` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
-- Дамп данных таблицы `country`
INSERT INTO `country` (`id`, `name`) VALUES
(1, 'Бульвар Рокоссовского'),
(2, 'Преображенская Площадь');
-- Структура таблицы `region`
CREATE TABLE `region` (
  `id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `countrys_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
-- Дамп данных таблицы `region`
INSERT INTO `region` (`id`, `countrys_id`, `name`) VALUES
(1, 1, '1-к '),
(2, 1, '2-к '),
(3, 1, '3-к '); 
-- Индексы сохранённых таблиц
-- Индексы таблицы `city`
ALTER TABLE `city`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);
-- Индексы таблицы `country`
ALTER TABLE `country`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);
-- Индексы таблицы `region`
ALTER TABLE `region`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);
ALTER TABLE `city`
  MODIFY `id` int(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=127;
ALTER TABLE `country`
  MODIFY `id` int(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=37;
ALTER TABLE `region`
  MODIFY `id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=4;
COMMIT;
```

Запросы БД для первого фильтра.

```
if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && !empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
require_once"connect.php";
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM city WHERE metroid = '".$_POST["country"]."' ");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
echo "<div class='infoFlat'>";
echo "<h3 value='".$row["id"]."'>".$row["metro"]."</h3>";
echo "<h3 value='".$row["id"]."'>".$row["room"]."</h3>";
echo "<p value='".$row["id"]."'>".$row["texts"]."</p>";
echo "<p value='".$row["id"]."'>".$row["price"]."</p>";
echo "</div>";
}
}
```

Запрос в БД для вывода данных Второго select.

```
(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && !empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {

require_once"connect.php";
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM region");

// var_dump($result);
echo"<option value=''>выберите Квартиру</option>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
echo "<option value='".$row["id"]."'>".$row["name"]."</option>";
}}
```

Код основной страницы.

```
<div>
<select id="get_country" name="get_country">
<!-- запрос в бд для вывода станций в первом select -->
<option value="">Выберите Метро</option>
<?php
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM country");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<option value='".$row["id"]."'>".$row["name"]."</option>";
}
 ?>
 </select>
 </div>
 <div id="sub_region">
 <select id="get_region" name="get_region">
<!-- Попытка заставить работать второй фильтр -->
<?php 
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM city WHERE `flatid` = '".$_POST['region']."' ");
echo"<option value=''>выберите Квартиру</option>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
echo "<option value='".$row["id"]."'>".$row["name"]."</option>";
echo "<div class='infoFlat'>";
echo "<h3 value='".$row["id"]."'>".$row["metro"]."</h3>";
 echo "<h3 value='".$row["id"]."'>".$row["room"]."</h3>";
echo "<p value='".$row["id"]."'>".$row["texts"]."</p>";
 echo "<p value='".$row["id"]."'>".$row["price"]."</p>";
echo "</div>";
}?></select></div>
<div id="sub_city" class="item">
 <div id="get_city" name="get_city">
<?php 
<!-- изначальный вывод всех статей в случайном порядке -->
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM city ORDER BY rand()");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<div class='infoFlat'>";
 echo "<h3 value='".$row["id"]."'>".$row["metro"]."</h3>";
 echo "<h3 value='".$row["id"]."'>".$row["room"]."</h3>";
 echo "<p value='".$row["id"]."'>".$row["texts"]."</p>";
 echo "<p value='".$row["id"]."'>".$row["price"]."</p>";
  echo "</div>";
}
?>
</div>
 </div>
```

JS программа для фильтрации

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#sub_region').css('display', 'none');
// $('#sub_city').css('display', 'none');
$("#get_country").change(function() {
clearlist();
$('#sub_city').css('display', 'none');      
var countryvalue = $("#get_country option:selected").val();
if (countryvalue === '') {clearlist(); }
if (countryvalue === '') {clearlist(); $('#sub_region').css('display', 'none');  }
getarea();
})
$("#get_region").change(function() {
clearlist();
$('#sub_city').css('display', 'none');      
var countryvalues = $("#get_region option:selected").val();
if (countryvalues === '') {clearlist(); }
if (countryvalues === '') {clearlist(); $('#sub_region').css('display', 'none');  }
getarea();
})
getarea();
getcity();
function getarea() {
var country_value = $("#get_country option:selected").val();
var regions_value = $("#get_region option:selected").val();
var p_id = $("#page_id").val();
var area = $("#get_city");
var getarea_value = area.val();
var p_reg_id = $("#page_id").val();
var area_region = $("#get_region");
var getareas_value = area_region.val();
if (country_value === "" && regions_value === country_value) {
area.attr("disabled",true);
area_region.attr("disabled",true);
} else {
area.attr("disabled",false);
area_region.attr("disabled",false);
area.load('get_city.php',{country : country_value, page_id : p_id});
area_region.load('get_region.php',{regions : regions_value, page_id : p_reg_id});
$('#sub_city').css('display', 'block');
}
$("#get_city").change(function() {
getcity();
})
}
function getcity() {
var country_value = $("#metroid").val();
var country_value = $("#get_city option:selected").val();
var regions_value = $("#flatid").val();
var regions_value = $("#get_city option:selected").val();
if((country_value == undefined) || (regions_value == "")){
var country_value = $("#metroid").val();
var regions_value = $("#flatid").val();
}
var p_id = $("#page_id").val();
var area = $("#get_region");
var p_reg_id = $("#page_id").val();
var area_region = $("#get_region");
if ((country_value === "") || (regions_value === "")) {
area.attr("disabled",true);
area_region.attr("disabled", true);
$('#sub_region').css('display', 'none');
$("#get_region").empty();
$('#sub_city').css('display', 'none');
$("#get_city").empty();
} else {
area.attr("disabled",false);
area.load('get_region.php',{region : country_value, page_id : p_id});
area_region.attr("disabled",false);
area_region.load('get_region.php',{regions : regions_value, page_id : p_reg_id});
$('#sub_region').css('display', 'block');
 }}
function clearlist() {
$("#get_region").empty();
$("#get_city").empty();
}});
```

Comment: Не пробовали во втором фильтре задать условие фильтрации? Как для первого

Comment: Я это и сделал , но ничего не вышло. Может я не внимателен? Второй фильтр убирает нужные статьи , вместо того , чтобы их показывать.

Comment: Я не вижу здесь `$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM region");` никакой фильтрации. Вижу вывод всей таблицы `region`

Comment: Вот она. Запрос в БД для вывода данных Второго select.

(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && !empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {

require_once"connect.php";
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM region");

// var_dump($result);
echo"<option value=''>выберите Квартиру</option>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
echo "<option value='".$row["id"]."'>".$row["name"]."</option>";
}}

Comment: Или я не так понял?

Comment: Этот код я видел. Объясните для себя что делает каждая строчка в нем

Comment: Этот код выводит данные из БД в select. Как я понимаю проблема в запросе sql, а не в js скрипте?  ?

Comment: Проблема в том, что у тебя во втором запросе отсутствует фильтр (WHERE)

Comment: то есть вместо $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM region");   Нужно $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM city WHERE `flatid` = '".$_POST['region']."' "); ?

Comment: Ну примерно так

Comment: А есть какой - то другой вариант? Я так делал, но не вышло - пропадают данные из второго select. Пытался совмещать запросы через AND и OR , тоже не то .

Comment: Ну значит ты неправильно совмещал. AND - то, что тебе нужно

Comment: Я совмещал запросы таким способом. $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM city WHERE metroid = '{$_POST["country"]}' AND flatid = '{$_POST["region"]}' ");

Comment: При AND Фильтры вообще не работают , а при OR только первый.

Comment: Столкнулся с похожей проблемой, но так и не нашел решения.

Comment: Уже не первый день бьюсь над задачей, кто-нибудь подскажите, как это решить ...